# getcwd() and file string leads to file-protocol-error

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, google-chrome

I want to load a javascript file from an absolute path in php but I keep getting an error called "Unable to load local resource".

I have an absolute path string like this

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo getcwd(); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>`

And get this as a result:
[image: Absolute Path leads to file:// Protocol]

How can I fix and avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you try copying that URI into your browser and see if the file opens/downloads?

Comment: @Tro, it just getting shown in the browsers view. I have read something about it in a forum that Chrome has a built-in security to block these file:-links from load them in-script.

Comment: Are you trying to use the standard jQuery library?

Comment: yes it is the standard jquery library but also other .js and .css-files. Same for all

Comment: If you're just wanting the jQuery library, you can use the Google hosted one (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js). The real way to resolve your problem would be to use the web URI location, `http://mywebsite.com/path/to/myscripts.js`, but this you would need to work out.

Comment: I am using jquery from a local file to improve loading speed of the page so this is not an alternative for me. Sorry.

Comment: @Tro do you have an idea?

Comment: Would the loading speed be acceptable if you accessed the javascript files using http served by your webserver rather than a file URI? I understand the files you are wanting to include are in a subdirectory of the main file you are loading, so if you include them on the web side you would avoid the permissions error in Chrome, but as it's served by your local machine it should still be acceptable speeds.

Comment: @Tro but there would be still the problem with the css and image-files...

Comment: Why do you not put all the images and css web-side as well? This is how websites work, and browser caching means load speed is a non-issue after the first visit (and you'll be using localhost anyway so negligible).

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using `file URI scheme`, which means that the browser will attempt to open a file that it is located on the client's computer and not to try to download it from the web server.

To fix this, you must provide a **relative path** starting from your **web project directory**

```
C:\yourDocumentRoot
   |
   |_project_one
     |_js
       |_jquery.js
       |_jquery-ui.js
```

And your **PHP** script must deliver this tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/project_one/js/jquery.js">
```

Hope that my explanation is clear :)

Comment: @HalayemAnis thanks for the answer :) but I have a .htaccess rewriterule to archive a text-based URL. and for that I need an absolute path to all the files which are located in the root-directory ;)